# Run matlab from WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

So I have matlab installed on my windows. I like to use the linux terminal on windows (through WSL2). Is there a way I can launch matlab from WSL?

Comment: Please explain in more details why you intend to run a Windows program on a Windows installation from WSL. Doesn't seem to make too much sense. What do you expect to achieve by doing that? Maybe there's a better wait to achieve your goals.

Comment: Well I often run matlab scripts from the command line. But it's a bit of a hassle to be changing from WSL to CMD.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  I think you'll find the answer to your question in the proposed duplicate, but if not, let me know via reply here.  Thanks!